# What can slow down Excel in copying worksheets, but doesn't slow down general responsiveness?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a fairly complex workbook that I'm building, and it looks like it's going to need a number of the sheets copied 10-20 times over - where each copy operation takes ~45s at the moment (over around 20 sheets). This seems unreasonable so I'm trying to trace what could be the culprit. So far I have:

- Disabled macros and addins prior to copying --> no effect
- Deleted all named ranges (the workbook contains a LOT of these, and each worksheet contains quite a number as well, many of which are dynamic, using the OFFSET(A1,,HEIGHT,WIDTH) approach) --> No effect
- Deleted all but a couple of sheets prior to copying --> no effect
- Ensured no formulae refer to very distant ranges --> no effect

In each case, I'm setting up the condition, closing the workbook and re-opening it prior to attempting a copy, and I should also mention that calculations are disabled (and in any event, despite a considerable number of volatile formulae, calculation takes still no more than around 5s, which should not result in a 45s copy time). Excel has plenty of memory available, so this SHOULDN'T be the issue, and I've tested on a machine with an SSD with the same results, which implies it's not a swap issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office?

Comment: 64-bit - though memory usage is around 500mb, working set ~404mb, so really shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: I assume you have tried to simply repair the Office installation?

Comment: Not as yet - mostly because it doesn't happen on fresh workbooks, so I'm pretty sure it's related to the workbook in question, not the Excel install.

Comment: Right, just finished repairing Excel. Same situation.

Comment: You are copying the sheets in excel and not in vba right?

Comment: I would rethink the structure. Copying anything 10-20 times seems inefficient and prone to errors, on top of the performance issues you are observing.  Rather than copying, I would try to add parameters e.g. named ranges that drive the 10-20 variations needed.  Or use Power Query Add-In to generate the copies systematically.

Comment: @gtwebb: I've tried both. The speeds are comparable. Eventually, I'll be copying them in VBA to build out the report with populated variables, though.

Comment: @Mike: There's already a LOT of named ranges driving the variations. The reason I need a lot of copies is because I need the same sheet with each member of several named ranges present in it. Haven't come across Power Query, though - will look into it. If it copies using it's own engine it might be more efficient, though since I experience the same slowdown when inserting a blank sheet, I doubt it. If it's just a matter of defining the parameters for the copy, I'll probably just use VB though (since the speed would be the same).

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Turned out that there was a local named range with a #REF error.  When I removed that name, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Find the last row, select down (Shift-down) and delete rows. Same for columns. It could be that someone applied a formatting on 1M lines.

Comment: As a general rule this is definitely the case. For the spreadsheet in question, it wasn't, though...

Comment: then you're doing sg you should do with a DB instead. Sometimes even 2000 rows can make thinhgs slower if the formulas are depend on each other. Especially SUMIFs and COUNTIFs I have experience with the can slow down things if you use $I:$I range instead of $I$1:$I$2222. Can't help more without the sheet itself.

Comment: It was a little more complex, though I never actually figured it out for the case in question. There were definitely no explicit uses of $I:$I (because I know that makes things crawl, and I never use it as a consequence). That said, I think there was some implicit usage of it (because for a lot of the pages, the used range would include the millionth row). Probably there was a name that evaluated relative to the selected cell, and I'd originally put it in referencing `A1` instead of `$A$1` with the cursor in cell `B2`. Or similar. Was definitely unusual though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, namely a blank sheet which I use as template and copy several times with different parameters to be able to compare different scenarios.

Copying the sheet either manually or via DBA became very slow at some point with no real reason for it - the template doesn't contain many formulas or even data.

However, when exploring the Name Manager, I found that there was a Print_Area name defined for that sheet and deleted it just for cleaning without thinking it would help. But it did; after deleting that the copy was near-instantaneous again.

Comment: OP had deleted all named ranges with no effect

Comment: Wow, question from a long while back. From memory, the culprit was a specific sheet that everything else relied upon (not deleted in my `all but a couple` condition above. With that gone, and names deleted, and the workbook and excel closed and re-opened, copying was fast again (but it wasn't a report any more). So I re-built that sheet from the ground up in another workbook, and avoided ever putting more than 20 or so sheets in with it ever, breaking the original 90 page task into 5 or so 15-page smaller ones.

Comment: Think the actual issue boils down to the XML structure that Excel is stored in and what that means for formulae when copying sheets. I've a feeling that certain operations cause Excel to re-structure references within the workbook, and potentially because of 30+ copies of the same name in different scopes (but potentially sharing `_rels` sheets internally), that operation ends up taking non-linear time. Small N (probably sheets * names) is fine, large, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the Conditional formatting is applied all over in duplicates and any operation is slowed due to all those conditions being processed for formatting.

Solution: Delete all conditional formatting in the sheet (or those you don't need) There are VBA codes to do that automatically if your sheet has hundreds of redundant ones in there - just Google 'vba to remove conditional formatting'